# Help with numerical procedure for coupled non-linear diffusion equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I am studying the dynamics of thin liquid films. In this context, I obtained the following set of equations:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(y^3\frac{\partial^3 y}{\partial x^3}+\frac{y}{2}r\right)=0,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+\alpha(1+\beta y)^2\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=0.
\end{equation}

The next step for me is to solve them numerically. I started by searching for similar equations in the literature, but could not find any. Moreover, advanced books on numerical analysis (Randall J. Leveque,  N Trefethen etc.) barley address solving non-linear equations. Any reference for books, names of similar equations, code, will be very helpful.

Edit:
$r=r(x,t)$, $y=y(x,t)$ are unknown functions which their solution I am looking for.

Comment: What is $r$? Is it known function? If it is, it seems that equation could be rewritten as ODE. Maybe a little bit nasty ODE, but still an ODE.

Comment: r=r(x,t) is also an unknown function.

Comment: In the second equation, is the $t$ derivative of $y$ or $r$?

Comment: y. There are no mistakes in the equations.

Comment: The problem with standard numerical techniques is that the analysis doesn't extend readily to nonlinear cases in terms of stability or error propagation, so it is difficult to "know" whether your computes solution approximates truth. In general, you can couple some kind of difference equation (Runge-Kutta, eg) with some kind of optimization search that fits the nonlinear terms.  For instance, if you are solving $y'=y^3$ the difference eqn could be $y_{i+1}-y_{i}=hy_{i+1}^3$.  To solve for $y_{i+1}$ you can run a Newton optimization scheme. Of course, all problems with optimizers apply.